# Unusual or archaic usage of "young"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, adjectives, archaicisms

> "Well, you've probably never been in a tighter place  than you are
> today! If there's a lunatic hiding on this island, he's probably got a
> **young arsenal** on him - to say nothing of a knife or dagger or two."
>
> *Agatha Christie - And Then There Were None.*

What does "young" mean here?

From context it could mean "small" or be an intensifier. I don't see these uses listed by online dictionaries, even as archaic. The sense of being recent doesn't seem to apply, but is another possibility.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've come across this usage, but I can't find it in the usual online dictionaries (Lexico, Collins, AHD, CED, M-W ...). I remember the expression 'young cannon', so I've searched for this.

From an article from 'The Authentic Campaigner', reviewing [*Three Years in the Confederate Horse Artillery*](https://www.authentic-campaigner.com/forum/showthread.php?14089-Swivel-guns-on-land) (tidied) by George Neese:

> *August 25 (1862) The sharpshooters were firing at each other across the river all night; The Yanks made three attempts last night to burn
> the bridge but our sharpshooters drove them back every time. This
> morning the Yanks on the hill near the bridge were firing swivels at
> us. A swivel is a species of young cannon – light, and mounted on a
> tripod that looks something like a surveyor's compass. The barrel is
> fixed on a swivel or turning point. The ones the Yanks fired at us
> this morning threw a shot about the size of a walnut. However I did
> not see any of them. I judge the size only by the keen whiz they made
> as they sped past us. I wonder what these Pope Yanks will try on us
> next – shoot a blacksmith shop or a buzz saw at us I expect. This
> forenoon we moved back to our wagons, about three miles from Waterloo
> bridge....*

The poster comments:

> *This is a first for me I've ever read of swivel guns being used by land forces: I've always considered them a ship feature. After all,
> what use is a small caliber round against artillery in the field?*
> [Gary Mitchell, 2nd Va. Cavalry Co. C, Stuart's horse artillery]

So a 'not quite' cannon.

A downtoner usage, not an intensifier. An archaic (the Christie example probably thwarts the 'obsolete' labelling) usage, but still sounding better than say 'He had what could almost be considered an arsenal with him.'

Comment: Is this possibly related to modern adj “baby”?

Comment: Yes, I would understand it to mean 'a small version of' something.

Comment: @StephenS It's the same metaphor, 'young/baby' = 'embryonic' = 'not quite full-blown'.

Comment: I don't think it's at all archaic, even if by some stretch of the imagination you could consider Christie archaic.  (Most of her books are still in copyright, and readily available in bookstores & public libraries.)  "Young something" is a common usage, at least in my observation.  Though I don't know how you'd do a search on that usage - even searching for just "young arsenal" gives mostly hits on a British football team :-(

Comment: 'downtoner'? As in Downton Abbey? or as in running out of it for your copy machine?

Comment: :-@ – jamesqf But surely, if it's still commonly used, you can readily find a few examples using a Google search? Use -Gunners -FC -Wenger -football -soccer etc filters.

Comment: @Mitch Without doubt, along the line of the terminology for instance in CGEL 7.33 (Some adjectives have a heightening effect on the noun they modify, or the reverse. At least three semantic subclasses of intensifying adjectives can be distinguished: a) emphasizers, b) amplifiers, c) downtoners.); "intensifier" must be a synonym for "amplifier".

Comment: @LPH It's a word I've never heard of. I couldn't tell you how it's pronounced - down-TOE-ner, DOWN-tuh-ner DOWN-TOE-ner. It's not in Merriam Webster (but is in others). What would I use instead (or rather what for me is the opposite) of intensifier? Deemphasize, minimize, mitigate, reduce. But 'downtone' is new to me even in linguistics.

Comment: @Mitch It probably has for etymology the verb "to tone down", meaning "lower or soften the tone of, make less emphatic". The pronunciation should follow from that.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth: But you have to know rather a lot about British football (or read a depressing number of the football links) to know what modifiers to use.  And FWIW, I did try the search with a -football, but still got mostly Arsenal football team references.

Comment: A couple of my secondary school teachers used this in the UK in the 1960s. If they were looking for a one-word or one-sentence answer and got something longer, they would complain that they didn't want a "young essay."

Comment: @LPH The etymology is obvious. It's just a very new usage to me [borne out by NGrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=downtoner&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3). Also, [in comparison to intensifier, extremely rare](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=downtoner%2C+intensifier&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3)

Comment: @Mitch Douglas Biber, Susan Conrad, and Geoffrey Leech, in the Longman Grammar of Spoken and Written English, 2002 [[Nordquist; ThoughtCo](https://www.thoughtco.com/degree-modifier-grammar-1690425)] list the term in its adverbial-describing usage. As LPH says, CGEL use it. [CED](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/downtoners) allows for a broadened usage, to include the fragment " ... _Kind of_" and the suffix _ish_, with the broadened definition 'Downtoners are words or phrases which reduce the force of another word or phrase.' // I'd considered 'mitigator' ...

Comment: but felt that that was too specific, implying here the concessive 'an arsenal, though admittedly not ...'. Perhaps '... not on the scale of that at Woolwich'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth OK. It's officially used, but I'm going to have to write a strongly worded letter to the authorities about their life choices.

Answer (score 4):

The oldest use I can find is from [Google Books](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=JN0_AAAAYAAJ&pg=PA133&dq=%22young+arsenal%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiKmNHYgqjtAhWRilwKHU6hDdUQ6AEwA3oECAEQAg#v=onepage&q=%22young%20arsenal%22&f=false)

> What do they have such a young arsenal in the house for? They treat us
> very well, but we don't know anything about them ; we might wake up
> any morning with our throats cut ...
>
> [The Princess of Montserrat: A Strange Narrative of Adventure ...books.google.co.uk › books -
> William Drysdale - 1890](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22young%20arsenal%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1914,cd_max:1926&lr=lang_en)

My best guess is that "young" is used in contrast to "mature". Although I don't see any references to "mature arsenal", I do see some that refer to a [mature collection](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22mature+collection%22&lr=lang_en&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1800,cd_max:1921,lr:lang_1en,sbd:1&tbm=bks&sxsrf=ALeKk03dNui_M2wPE0TRT61SXS3kO8ta5A:1606663449740&source=lnt&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjCvsfhh6jtAhUlpnEKHZ3bDGkQpwUIJQ&biw=1600&bih=775&dpr=1.2) I searched for this because it is a term I am familiar with.

**Conclusion**

Although I cannot be certain, I believe that "young arsenal" refers to a collection of weapons that is *still growing* but is in its initial stages. Eventually it will become a mature collection.

Comment: I'd disagree with the "still growing" meaning.  Rather, it's a rather complicated way of expressing the large size.  That is, an arsenal is mainly understood to be a weapons depot for an army, so calling a personal collection of weapons a "young arsenal" expresses the idea that it's an extraordinarily large amount for an individual or small group.

Comment: To wit: we might today refer to a "*fledgling* arsenal" with the same intended meaning.